# Creating permutations of tree diagram dynamically and scalable

Tags: python, tree, permutation, python-itertools

I am trying to create permutations which follows a datatree design in Python. The root should be dynamically and could contain a list of lists.

[This image shows how the permutations should be created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCPUx.png)

Arrows show allowed combinations.

[This image explains what could be combined in each level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW6q6.png)

I have tried using itertools.permutations without getting the right results as the lists are too deep.

- The array should be handled dynamically as the size of the lists
  could differ on all levels.
- The items in the different lists on each level should not be combined
  but the items inside of each list must be.
- Only one list should be included in the combination from each layer

List = List with one or more strings inside
Level = List with multiple or one list inside

Example code of input:

```
[
 [
  ["8F10"], ["8F12"], ["8F11"]
 ],
 [
  ["8F10"], ["8F12"], ["8F11"]
 ],
 [
  ["8F10"], ["8F12"], ["8F11"]
 ],
 [
  ["FW03", "8F10"], ["FW03", "8F12"], ["FW03", "8F11"]
 ],
 [
  ["8F12"], ["8F10"], ["8F11"]
 ],
 [
  ["8F10", "KE04"], ["8F11", "KE04"], ["8F12", "KE04"]
 ],
 [
  ["8F11"], ["8F12"], ["8F10"]
 ],
 [
  ["8F10"], ["8F11"], ["8F12"]
 ],
 [
  ["8F10"], ["8F11"], ["8F12"]
 ],
 [
  ["9T03", "8F10"], ["9T03", "8F11"], ["9T03", "8F12"]
 ]
]
```

EDIT:

Expected results could be a list of tuples with each permutation (combination) like itertools.permutations.

Example of expected results (one tuple):

```
[
 (["8F10"], ["8F10"], ["8F10"], ["FW03"], ["8F10"], ["8F12"], ["8F10"], ["KE04"], ["8F11"], ["8F10"], ["8F10"], ["9T03"], ["8F10"]), 
 (["8F10"], ["8F12"], ["8F10"], ["FW03"], ["8F10"], ["8F12"], ["8F10"], ["KE04"], ["8F11"], ["8F10"], ["8F10"], ["9T03"], ["8F10"]), 
 ...
]
```

Input and output can be adjusted (if it's list, tuple, dictionary and so on) but the important task is to get all permutations/combinations possible.

The grouping cannot be adjusted, for example ["FW03", "8F10"] cannot be split as they are depended of each other.

Comment: Please provide some example of expected outputs.

Comment: Post edited with example of expected output.

Comment: *"...but the items inside of each list can be."*: does this mean it is *optional* to include *all* the items from a sublist? Or is it required? In your examples you always include all items in a subarray, **and** in their proper order. There seem to be rules here that you have not specified.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Items inside of a list, for example: ["FW03", "8F10"] are required to be together (see last sentence above).
For one "level" only one of the list (items inside the square brackets) should be included in the permutation/combination. Example of a level is:
[
  ["FW03", "8F10"], ["FW03", "8F12"], ["FW03", "8F11"]
 ],

This is also illustrated in the second picture (second link in the post)

Comment: Yes, my comment was about the sublists only. So it is not *"can be"*, but *"must be, and in that order"*.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it should be must be. But the order is not important. Only that it is included in the permutations/combination. Will edit that part. Thanks.

Comment: *"order is not important"*: does that mean that all permutations of the sublist should be generated and should be included in the output as *different* combinations? Or does that mean that it doesn't matter, and we can take any order (so why not the original order)... but other orders need not to be considered?

Comment: "This image shows how the permutations should be created" I have absolutely no idea how to interpret the image. "Arrows show allowed combinations." isn't enough explanation for me, sorry.

Comment: How the combination is ordered is not important, with that i mean which string is in the beginning of the tuple or at the end.
The intention is to get different combinations at the end. If it's easier to get it done directly then that is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your input is available by the name `data`, then the following will create an iterator over the possible combinations:

```
it = (tuple(itertools.chain(*x)) for x in itertools.product(*data))
```